# EmguCV vs2012 visualizer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, emgucv

I'm using EmguCV in VS2012.

Following [this tutorial](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Debugger_Visualizer), I copied the dlls into VS debugger directory. However when I click the "view" icon on the variable, there's an error like this:

```
Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core249'
```

And other parts of the program just works fine.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I know that the question is quite old... but i answer for people googling for this, like me)

I'm having the same issue...

As a workaround, I have put OpenCV DLLs' dir (i.e. <EmguCVInstallDir>\bin\x86) in the system PATH environment variable... and now visualizers work like a charm!

Hope this helps

Comment: I solved this by adding C:\Emgu\emgucv-windesktop 3.4.3.3016\libs\x86 and C:\Emgu\emgucv-windesktop 3.4.3.3016\libs\x64 to the system path

Answer (score 0):

I make a webforms project and works fine but now I try to use emgu in a mvc project and I have the CVInvoke problem, I don't know where put the opencv dll to use with IIS express for debugger